# How to reproduce a "stamped type" effect in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

I'm working on an illustration and want to have an effect such that the type looks imprinted into a textured leather background, as if it had been stamped in place.

**Examples:**
[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

In the real world, this would be a combination of deformation (embossing), and then you'd color or gild the interior of the type to make it stand out even more.

I've tried using the Emboss function of the type tool, but the effects were miserable. Have you successfully replicated this look?

Comment: Inner shadow layer effect.

Answer (score 6):

add a type layer; layer effects: emboss with conservative "low value" settings and 'chisel hard'; gradient overlay effect using colors from the gold.

Mimic the foil overstamping by duplicating text layer; set layer fill to 0%; add a 1px outer stroke effect using color sampled from gold at a low opacity.

[image]